# Hybrid Exchange - 3 step deprovisioning necessary when using archive

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, exchangeonline, exchange-hybrid

The Microsoft [documentation for the `Disable-RemoteMailbox` powershell cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/disable-remotemailbox) states:

> Note: If you are deprovisioning a cloud mailbox and its associated
> online archive, you must first disable the online archive with the
> command `Disable-RemoteMailbox -Archive` and then perform a directory
> synchronization prior to disabling the remote mailbox. Attempting to
> disable both the online archive and cloud mailbox without a sync
> between them may result in an `ArchiveGuid` mismatch and validation
> error.

So 3 steps are required to deprovision a mailbox correctly:

1. Call `Disable-RemoteMailbox "David Strome" -Archive`
2. Wait for the AD Connect directory synchronization
3. `Disable-RemoteMailbox "David Strome"`

Is step #2 necessary if you also disable the on-premise AD user and you exclude disabled users from the directory synchronization, effectively deleting the AAD user and eventually the user and archive mailboxes?

If the person comes back for a new work period, the on-premise AD user is enabled. That may happen within the 30 days retention period for the mailboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still recommended that you perform step 2 and it only takes 1-2 minutes to force synchronization.

To force a synchronization from AD to Azure AD PowerShell is used. To perform a delta synchronization run:

Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta

To perform a full synchronization use:

Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial

Comment: We reached the same conclusion after reading this:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office365/troubleshoot/archive-mailboxes/cannot-provision-deprovision

We are going to poll the on-premise AD user property msExchRemoteRecipientType to see if the archive has been deprovisioned before performing step 3. Our application does not have access to start a synchronization and poll for its completion.